# Правильно ли я использую сетку Bootstrap для создания адаптивного сайта?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Верстаю свою первую страницу на сетке Bootstrap. Появились сомнения в правильности некоторых решений. Например, как изменять размер шрифта и расстояние между строками (row) на разных экранах? Через медиа-запросы или есть какой то другой способ (классы...?)

Answer (score 0):

Размер шрифта меняете в медиа-запросах;
Для изменения размеров блоков используете классы bootstrap, например, col-md-6, где md-обозначение среднего разрения экрана, а 6-количество колонок из 12, которые займет блок. Расстояние между row можете указывать в медиа-запросах

Comment: Про блоки понятно, да и в целом я все так и предполагал. Спасибо за ответ!